# Need help for pose estimation of an object using open cv c++

Tags: opencv, pose-estimation, extrinsic-parameters

I have the intrinsic and distortion matrix from a calibrated camera. I am using open cv 3.2 c++. I am getting error output of pose estimation of the object. Help me to sort out this error. The values and the error image are attached below.

```
Mat K = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 5489.58773029126, 0, 1167.86282865392, 0, 5481.84660546223, 1047.21450461614, 0, 0, 1);
Mat dist = (Mat_<double>(1, 5) << -0.111931171641671, 0.087488429523756156, 0.000844290429230941, 0.00204127293599477,0);
```

I already have image and object points, so proceeding with solvepnp for getting rotation and translation vector.So,

```
Mat rvecs, tvecs;
vector<Point3f> end_point3D;
vector<Point2f> end_point2D;
end_point3D.push_back(Point3f(50, 0, 0));
end_point3D.push_back(Point3f(0, 50, 0));
end_point3D.push_back(Point3f(0, 0, 50));

solvePnP(Object_points, Image_points, K, dist, rvecs, tvecs);
projectPoints(end_point3D, rvecs, tvecs, K, dist, end_point2D, noArray(), 0.0);

    cv::line(image, Image_points[0], end_point2D[0], cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 6);
    cv::line(image, Image_points[0], end_point2D[1], cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 6);
    cv::line(image, Image_points[0], end_point2D[2], cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 6);
```

The image is given below.[error output of estimated pose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwwal.png)

**EDIT:** The object points and image points are ordered properly in the same way. I am sure about the ordering, I have done the row-major ordering.

```
Size sq_size(6, 6);
int  Sq_length = 30;
vector<Point3f>Object_points;

for (int r = 0; r < sq_size.height; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < sq_size.width; c++)
        Object_points.push_back(Point3f(r*Sq_length, c*Sq_length, 0));

vector<Point2f>Image_points;
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    Image_points.push_back((Point2f)op_cent[i]);
//row-major ordered image points
```

I have two doubts,
1.Though they are properly ordered, sometimes the pose results wrong as shown below, What could be the reason?

[Error pose output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnT5o.png)

2.If I draw, estimated pose only at Image_points[0], it comes out to be right,but not at any other points. Can someone explain why the pose is wrong at Image_points[30]? At any point the objects pose should be same right?

Comment: It is hard to just tell you what is wrong just by looking at an image of the coordinate system. You should add more info, like how the object points were created, or how the image points look like and if the order of both is correct.

Comment: @api55 kindly find the edited description. I guess there is some error other than ordering.

Comment: what do you mean with question 2? you use the same projection but starting from another point? actually, you should use the origin and translate it in any case, but equally... so, if points[0] is (0,0,0) (as describe in your 3D points passed to solvepnp) then this means it is the origin, creates 3 lines representing the axis. In your case, if you use points[1] you should translate the endpoints as well, for 1, it should be translated +30 in y of each point.  and it should be ok.  For 1) maybe your image points are too noisy, or maybe you can try with another method

Comment: @api55 Thank you for the explanation! Question 1 was solved (One of the image points was wrong). For Question 2, your answer cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

[`solvePnP`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga549c2075fac14829ff4a58bc931c033d) (documentation is for OpenCV 4.0.1, visit https://docs.opencv.org/ to browse the correct documentation according to your OpenCV version) **needs at least 4 points** to compute the camera pose.

You are using OpenCV 3.2 but an assert has been added in later OpenCV version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had to use open cv 3.2 for my current application.

Comment: @van4 Just add a fourth point and it should be good. There are mathematically up to 4 solutions with P3P and EPNP is applicable for 4 points or more.

Comment: I have totally 36 object and respective image points. I have used EPNP, still getting wrong results for certain images.

Answer (score 0):

I currently working to write software about pose estimation. but your problem description is not really clear to me. perhaps you can make more updated view on your case.

here is my opinions that might be helpful:

I use initial rotation and translation in rvecs and tvecs, I input those initial position as mat object, I need 3 initial rotation and 3 initial position. the solvePnP will take it as initial starting point for further calculation. it gives me pretty accurate results.

for your code, you give too little information for me to make a comment on what was going on before/after those code.